# vCenter: how to add new IP range to a Distributed Switch

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

I have a distributed switch set up in my vCenter with 2 hosts.

Recently I ordered a new IP range which comes with a Gateway address.
The IPs are assigned to the correct VLAN, my question is, how do I set this up so that I can choose which Guest OS can use one of the new IPs.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide the version and license level of your VMware installation.

Comment: I have vCenter Server 5 standard with vSphere 5 Enterprise Plus

Comment: Might be way too obvious; did you assign a static IP to the guest OS you want to have the new IP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll instructions for the vSphere Windows client for now. The concepts in the web interface are similar, but the execution is slightly different...

1). You'll need to create a new port group in your distributed switch... Typically, your uplink ports from the Distributed Switch will be trunks with multiple VLANs.

[image]

---

2). In the vSphere client, go to the `Home -> Inventory -> Networking` screen. Locate the Distributed Switch on the left pane. Right-click the top-level switch and add a new "Port Group". If the port group already exists, all you'll need to do is skip to the last step...

[image]

---

3). Give it an appropriate name and fill in VLAN details, etc. From there, you can just choose the right network for the virtual machine from the VM's "Network Connection" dialog.

[image]